# Starting responsiveslides only when user clicks on link/button

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-slides

I was able to get this working on a site I'm creating: http://jsbin.com/eHaHEVuN/1/ (found it in 
[How to start/stop ResponsiveSlides.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765815/how-to-start-stop-responsiveslides-js))

The slideshow starts automatically until it gets paused with a click. What I need is for the slideshow not to start until the user clics on PLAY. That is, there would be no slideshow until PLAY is clicked. (I tried the setting `auto: false` and the slideshow indeed starts out paused, but I cannot get the PLAY link to display nor can I get the slideshow started.)

I'm not well-versed, so code I can copy/paste would be enormously appreciated. The slideshow is currently at http://new.ceciliaportal.com/slideshow-test.html
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that it is coded for autoplay, so the "Play Slider" link is hidden by default and the "Pause Slider" link is displayed. This is a simple fix. Set `auto` to `false` in your slider settings and in the CSS change `.play_slider { display:none; }` to `.pause_slider { display:none; }`

## [Updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/tuyitovatezu/1/edit)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried doing as you suggested, but the slideshow will not start at all, no matter what I press. Also, the PAUSE link shows until I press it and then it switches to PLAY, without starting the slideshow.